# varnishd: command not found

Tags: centos, varnish

New machine running CentOS 5.6, httpd & mysql installed and operational. 
I've installed Varnish through yum without any error but I'm unable to run the `varnished`

For example, if I want to run the following command as seen on the Varnish-wiki:

`varnishd -f /usr/local/etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:8080`

I'm prompted with the following response `-bash: varnishd: command not found`

Running `varnishadm` works and results in `Child in state running`
, confirming that varnish is indeed running.

I've tried all of the above with `sudo`as well but no avail.
I do not have root access on this machine, could that be what's causing this? Any other things I can check?

Comment: Question: First is varnishd present on the system?  IF so, what is it's full path?  Does your PATH variable contain the directory where varnishd is located?  Any information from the man page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On my CentOS system varnishd is `/usr/sbin/varnishd`. Check that your PATH has `/usr/sbin` in it.

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin
which varnishd
/usr/sbin/varnishd
```